# Is there a shortcut in TeXstudio for autocompletion?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

Is there a shortcut in TeXstudio for autocompletion?
For example when I started to write \ref and then went to find out the name and got back, now the suggestions won't appear without deleting and writing \ref again.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, Ctrl+space does the job.